# My XPath in Google Sheets IMPORTXML command always returns #N/A

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to scrape some data from the website Sporcle (specifically the Date Earned from one of the Badges) but the XPath that I got from [F12-->right-clicking the element-->Copy-->Copy XPath] does not seem to work with the google sheets command IMPORTXML; all I ever get is #N/A.

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.sporcle.com/user/Jimmy/badges/earned/","//*[@id='badge-container']/div[1]/div[3]")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Website uses dynamic rendering. So, classic methods don't work. I see 3 ways to  do it :

- With `IMPORTXML` : we retrieve the JSON data from a script element and we parse it with formulas.
- With `IMPORTXML`+[ImportJSON](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/ae64c908b82cc8cf8840e176930ad937883fbe37/ImportJSON.gs) script : we retrieve the JSON data from a script element and we parse it with the script (cleaner).
- With [IMPORTFROMWEB](https://nodatanobusiness.com/importfromweb/) addon (number of requests are limited in the "free" plan).

**Solution 1 :**

Output :[image]

First, we extract the JSON data in `A1` with `IMPORTXML` and the following formula :

```
=IMPORTXML(B1;"substring-before(substring-after(//*[contains(text(),'badge_limiter')],'var badgeList = [{'),'}]')")
```

Then we parse the data with a combination of multiple formulas. In `J2` we write :

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUE(SUBSTITUE(SUBSTITUE(REGEXREPLACE(M1;"(""\w+?_\w+?"":)";"");""",";""";");"""";"");"},";"");"{"));";"));"select Col1,Col6")
```

**Solution 2 :**

Output :
[image: IJS]

First, we extract the JSON data in `A1` with `IMPORTXML` and the following formula :

```
=IMPORTXML(B1;"substring-before(substring-after(//*[contains(text(),'badge_limiter')],'var badgeList = '),'}]')")&"}]"
```

Then we parse the data with the script. Formula used in `F1` is :

```
=ImportJSONFromSheet("Feuille 15";"/badge_name,/earned_date")
```

Where `Feuille 15` is the name of the sheet I'm working with. The rest is to select the columns of interest.

**Solution 3 :**

Output :
[image: IFW]

XPath used for badges names and dates :
:

```
//td[@class='left-align link-col col-width-1']
//td[@class="col-width-3"]
```

Then we pass the formula in `B5`:

```
=IMPORTFROMWEB(C1;C2:D2;B3:C3)
```

Note : be sure to set `jsRendering` to `TRUE`.

Side note : I'm based in Europe, so you'll probably need to replace `;` with `,` in the formulas.